# Monotonicty of the trace on Sobolev spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, trace

> Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary and suppose $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. If $v\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ satisfies $\lvert v \rvert \leq \lvert u \rvert$ in all of $\Omega$, can we conclude that $v\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

Clearly, the statement is true if we assume that $u$ and $v$ are continuous up to the boundary of $\Omega$. More generally, the statement "feels" true and almost intuitive, but I have no idea how to solve or approach the problem.

Thanks in advance for any idea or references about this problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, we will use that there for $u\geq0\Rightarrow tr(u)\geq0$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635828)
 for ideas on a proof.

Secondly, we will use that for $u\in W^{1,p}$ also $u^+=\max(0,u)\in W^{1,p}$ and similarly $u^-=\min(0,u)\in W^{1,p}$.

Thirdly, we will use the trace Operator which is a continuous linear Operator from $W^{1,p}\to L^p$ which allows the following identification $W^{1,p}_0=\{u\in W^{1,p}|tr(u)=0\}$.

Now, we start by splitting the functions into
$$
u=u^++u^-\\
v=v^++v^-\\
|v|\leq|u|\Leftrightarrow v^+\leq u^+\wedge u^-\leq v^-
$$

Now since 
$$0\leq tr(u^+-v^+)=tr(u^+)-tr(v^+)=-tr(v^+)\leq0$$
and
$$0\leq tr(v^--u^-)=tr(v^-)-tr(u^-)=tr(v^-)\leq0$$
we can deduct that
$$tr(u)=tr(u^++u^-)=tr(u^+)+tr(u^-)=0$$